# Cone rotation around apex with Cesium.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, cesiumjs

I am trying to rotate a cone from its apex, rather than its centre, so that the apex remains in the same position.

I've found the example below from the following link:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cesium-dev/f9ZiSWPMgus

But it only shows how to rotate the cone by 90 degrees, if you choose a different value for roll, like 45 or 30 degrees, it gets skewed, and the apex ends up in the wrong place.

I know its something to do with the offset, but can't make any progress from there. Is there some way to calculate the correct offset for any value of roll?

I'd also like to extend the length of the cone when its rotated, so that when its rotated 30 degrees for example, the bottom of the cone will still reach the ground in that direction, while the apex still remains in its original place, I don't know how feasible that is though.

Here's a glitch of the code sample below:
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/cesium-cone-rotation

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');

var position = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-75, 40, 90); 

//Original, non-rotated cone for comparison.
viewer.entities.add(new Cesium.Entity({
    position: position,
    point: {
        color: Cesium.Color.YELLOW,
        show: true,
        pixelSize: 20
    },
    cylinder: {
        topRadius: 0,
        bottomRadius: 45,
        length: 180,
        material: Cesium.Color.YELLOW.withAlpha(0.5)
    }
}));

var heading = Cesium.Math.toRadians(0.0);
var pitch = Cesium.Math.toRadians(0.0);
var roll = Cesium.Math.toRadians(90.0);
var hpr = new Cesium.HeadingPitchRoll(heading, pitch, roll);

//Create a rotation
var orientation = Cesium.Transforms.headingPitchRollQuaternion(position, hpr);

// offset the rotation so it's rotating from the apex of the cone, instead of the centre
var offset = new Cesium.Cartesian3(0, 90, 90);

//Create a transform for the offset.
var enuTransform = Cesium.Transforms.eastNorthUpToFixedFrame(position);

//Transform the offset
Cesium.Matrix4.multiplyByPointAsVector(enuTransform, offset, offset);

//Add the offset to the original position to get the final value.
Cesium.Cartesian3.add(position,  offset,  position);

viewer.entities.add(new Cesium.Entity({
    position: position,
    orientation: orientation,
    point: {
        color: Cesium.Color.YELLOW,
        show: true,
        pixelSize: 20
    },
    cylinder: {
        topRadius: 0,
        bottomRadius: 45,
        length: 180,
        material: Cesium.Color.YELLOW.withAlpha(0.5)
    }
}));

viewer.zoomTo(viewer.entities);
```

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I came up with to rotate and translate a cylinder when you want to point it in a specific orientation specified by an azimuth and elevation.

```
/**
 * Calculate the position and orientation needed for the beam entity.
 * @param {Cesium.Cartesian3} position - The position of the desired origin.
 * @param {Number} az - The azimuth of the beam center in radians.
 * @param {Number} el - The elevation of the beam center in radians.
 * @param {Number} range - The range of the beam in meters.
 * 
 * @returns {[Cesium.Cartesian3, Cesium.Quaternion]} Array of the position and
 * orientation to use for the beam.
 */
calculateBeam(position, az, el, range) {
    // The origin of Cesium Cylinder entities is the center of the cylinder.
    // They are also pointed straight down towards the local East-North plane. The
    // math below rotates and translates the cylinder so that its origin is the tip
    // of the cylinder and its orientation is pointed in the direction specified by
    // the az/el.
    let heading = az - Cesium.Math.toRadians(90);
    let pitch = Cesium.Math.toRadians(90) + el;
    let hpr = new Cesium.HeadingPitchRoll(heading, pitch, 0.0);
    let x = range/2.0 * Math.sin(pitch) * Math.cos(heading);
    let y = -range/2.0 * Math.sin(heading) * Math.sin(pitch);
    let z = -range/2.0 * Math.cos(pitch);
    var offset = new Cesium.Cartesian3(x, y, z);
    let enuTransform = Cesium.Transforms.eastNorthUpToFixedFrame(position);
    Cesium.Matrix4.multiplyByPointAsVector(enuTransform, offset, offset);
    let newPosition = Cesium.Cartesian3.add(position, offset, new Cesium.Cartesian3());
    let orientation = Cesium.Transforms.headingPitchRollQuaternion(position, hpr);
    return [newPosition, orientation];
}
```

This will give you the position/orientation to use when you create the cylinder entity. It will place the cylinder such that the tip of the cylinder is located at 'position' and it is pointed in the direction specified by the azimuth and elevation. Azimuth is relative to North with positive angles towards East. Elevation is relative to the North-East plane, with positive angles up. Range is the length of the cylinder.

This doesn't get you the behavior you wanted as far as lengthening the cylinder as you rotate it, but hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as you. This is my reference code. This is a function of computing the matrix of a cone at any angle.

```
 computedModelMatrix(Cartesian3: any, attitude: any, length: any) {
        //锥体距离卫星的高度
        let oldLength = length / 2;
        let centerCartesian3 = new Cesium.Cartesian3(Cartesian3.x, Cartesian3.y, Cartesian3.z);
        let oldX = 0, oldY = 0, oldZ = -oldLength, newX = 0, newY = 0, newZ = 0;
        let heading = attitude.heading;
        //规定顺时针为正旋转,正东方向为0度
        if (heading < 0) {
            heading = heading + 360;
        }
        let roll = attitude.roll;
        let pitch = attitude.pitch;
        let headingRadians = Cesium.Math.toRadians(heading);
        let pitchRadians = Cesium.Math.toRadians(pitch);
        let rollRadians = Cesium.Math.toRadians(roll);
        let hpr = new Cesium.HeadingPitchRoll(headingRadians, pitchRadians, rollRadians);
        let orientation = Cesium.Transforms.headingPitchRollQuaternion(centerCartesian3, hpr);
        //旋转roll
        newY = oldY + oldLength * Math.sin(rollRadians);
        newZ = oldZ + oldLength - oldLength * Math.cos(rollRadians);
        let pitchTouying = oldLength * Math.cos(rollRadians);//进行pitch变化时在Y轴和Z轴组成的平面的投影
        //旋转pitch
        newX = oldX + pitchTouying * Math.sin(pitchRadians);
        newZ = newZ + (pitchTouying - pitchTouying * Math.cos(pitchRadians));
        if (heading != 0) {
            let headingTouying = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.abs(newX), 2) + Math.pow(Math.abs(newY), 2));//进行heading变化时在Y轴和X轴组成的平面的投影
            //旋转heading
            let Xdeg = Cesium.Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(Math.abs(newX) / Math.abs(headingTouying)));//现有投影线与X轴的夹角
            let newXdeg = 0;//旋转heading后与X轴的夹角
            let newXRadians = 0;//旋转heading后与X轴的夹角弧度
            if (newX >= 0 && newY >= 0) {
                newXdeg = heading - Xdeg;
            } else if (newX > 0 && newY < 0) {
                newXdeg = heading + Xdeg;
            } else if (newX < 0 && newY > 0) {
                newXdeg = heading + (180 + Xdeg);
            } else {
                newXdeg = heading + (180 - Xdeg)
            }
            if (newXdeg >= 360) {
                newXdeg = 360 - newXdeg;
            }
            if (newXdeg >= 0 && newXdeg <= 90) {
                newXRadians = Cesium.Math.toRadians(newXdeg);
                newY = -headingTouying * Math.sin(newXRadians);
                newX = headingTouying * Math.cos(newXRadians);
            } else if (newXdeg > 90 && newXdeg <= 180) {
                newXRadians = Cesium.Math.toRadians(180 - newXdeg);
                newY = -headingTouying * Math.sin(newXRadians);
                newX = -headingTouying * Math.cos(newXRadians)
            } else if (newXdeg > 180 && newXdeg <= 270) {
                newXRadians = Cesium.Math.toRadians(newXdeg - 180);
                newY = headingTouying * Math.sin(newXRadians);
                newX = -(headingTouying * Math.cos(newXRadians))
            } else {
                newXRadians = Cesium.Math.toRadians(360 - newXdeg);
                newY = headingTouying * Math.sin(newXRadians);
                newX = headingTouying * Math.cos(newXRadians)
            }
        }
        let offset = new Cesium.Cartesian3(newX, newY, newZ);
        let newPosition = this.computeOffset(centerCartesian3, offset);
        return Cesium.Matrix4.fromTranslationQuaternionRotationScale(newPosition, orientation, new Cesium.Cartesian3(1, 1, 1))
    }
computeOffset(Cartesian3: any, offset: any) {
        let enuTransform = Cesium.Transforms.eastNorthUpToFixedFrame(Cartesian3);
        Cesium.Matrix4.multiplyByPointAsVector(enuTransform, offset, offset);
        return Cesium.Cartesian3.add(Cartesian3, offset, new Cesium.Cartesian3());
    }
```