# WebGL-earth elevation/altitude?

Tags: javascript, point, webgl-earth

I have been searching for an example of plotting a point/marker in space given the latitude, longitude and altitude/elevation but i cannot find it in the documentation or on any other question. Is it possible to plot a marker in space using WebGL-earth?

Comment: you might find [this tutorial useful](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-optimize-lots-of-objects.html), it's followed by 3 more tutorials all related to making WebGL Earth like stuff

Comment: I am struggling to solve same issue in CesiumJS, did you find a solution?

Comment: @jumpjack i managed to find a solution using CesiumJS. Im not sure if it will help you but maybe look into the Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees. It solved my issues.    `item.position=Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(lon_coordinates,lat_coordinates,alt_coordinates); `

Comment: but this gives you only the ability to locate a point on surface! But maybe I misunderstood: by altitude/elevation you meant height above ground, while I meant angular elevation, as in "altitude/azimuth coordinate system".

Comment: I couldn't find anything for azimuth so I had converted my data to work with this method. Not the greatest solution but it was a workout that worked for my project.

Comment: Several answers now available: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42941855/cone-rotation-around-apex-with-cesium-js  , https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/379147/convert-from-alt-az-coordinates-w-r-t-point-on-surface-to-x-y-z-w-r-t-earth-c/379173#379173  , https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/379843/how-to-properly-point-the-sun-in-cesiumjs/380198#380198 , https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/379843/how-to-properly-point-the-sun-in-cesiumjs